# Set admin Facebook comment box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm tried with some posts here but not work for me! 
This is my App setting on Facebook develope (sr, don't have enough reputation):

App Domains : localhost 
Site URL: http://localhost:50031/ 
App Id: 570146336422

Here is my meta in head tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="570146336422" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:50031/" />
```

And this is my code in body tag

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
      (function (d, s, id) {
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=570146336422";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:50031/" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

But I can't get Admin role for my page

Comment: Facebook needs to be able to read the meta tags, so it needs to be able to request your URL first – and that is not possible as long as you are testing this on your localhost. You need to make the page publicly available over the internet, before this can work.

Comment: I saw some topic about how to set admin, and they made sure it worked. Unfortunately, It didn't worked with me. But It works perfectly in real host.
Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According CBone's answer comment. The Facebook can't read your meta tag in localhost, but it will be worked correctly in real host over the Internet